# how to await if there are no functions?

Tags: javascript, cryptocurrency

I am trying to run a simple javascript code straight from the documentation, but for some reason it's resulting in an error-

"`SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`"

```js
const { MnemonicKey,Coin,MsgSwap,LCDClient,MsgExecuteContract } = require('@terra-money/terra.js');

const lcd = new LCDClient({
  URL: 'https://lcd.terra.dev',
 // URL: 'https://falling-empty-waterfall.terra-mainnet.quiknode.pro/94818b47fef9194193d08f7ffdc9e90ffdcdee17/',
  chainId: 'columbus-5'
});


const mk = new MnemonicKey({
    mnemonic: 'mnemo',
})


// UST <> SCRT
const pool = "terra1tq4mammgkqrxrmcfhwdz59mwvwf4qgy6rdrt46";

// Fetch the number of each asset in the pool.
const { assets } = await lcd.wasm.contractQuery(pool, { pool: {} });

// Calculate belief price using pool balances.
const beliefPrice = (assets[0].amount / assets[1].amount).toFixed(18);

// Swap 1 UST to SCRT with 1% slippage tolerance.
const terraSwap = new MsgExecuteContract(
  wallet.key.accAddress,
  pool, 
  {
    swap: {
      max_spread: "0.01",
      offer_asset: {
        info: {
          native_token: {
            denom: "uusd",
          },
        },
        amount: "1000000",
      },
      belief_price: beliefPrice,
    },
  },
  new Coins({ uusd: '1000000' }),
);

const tx = await wallet.createAndSignTx({ msgs: [terraSwap] });
const result = await lcd.tx.broadcast(tx);

console.log(result);
```

What could I be missing?
Thank you.

P.s this code is taken straight from the documentation - https://docs.terra.money/docs/develop/sdks/terra-js/common-examples.html

Comment: *"this code is taken straight from the documentation"* Well, no, it isn't. The documentation clearly shows using JavaScript standard modules (`import`/`export`), not CommonJS modules. And the error message clearly says that `await` can be used in modules. (It should be more specific.) Switch to [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) and the problem will go away.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in async function or in async IIFE

Comment: Or do what the documentation shows: Use JavaScript standard modules, not CommonJS.